# Alternative definition on free modules.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, free-modules, free-abelian-group

I 'm trying to compare Free Modules and Free Abelian Groups.

We know that,

> **Definition.** An abelian group $G$ is called *free abelian group with rank $n\in \Bbb N^*$*, if $G$ is the direct sum of $n$ infinite cyclic groups. That is, 
>   $$G=\langle x_1 \rangle \oplus ... \oplus \langle x_n \rangle$$
>   where $U_i:=\langle x_i \rangle, \ i=1,...,n$ are infinite cyclic groups. Then, $x_1,...,x_n$  are called *free generators* of $G$, $X:=\{x_1,...,x_n\}$  is called *basis (or free generators set)* of $G$ and $n$ is called *rank* of $G$.

We already know the following definition that seems equivalent.

> **Definition.** Let $R$ be a ring with $1_R$. An $R$-module $F$ is called *free* on a subset $A$ of $F$, if for every nonzero element $x\in F$, there exist unique nonzero elements $r_1,...,r_n\in R$ and unique
>   $a_1,...a_n \in A$ such that  $$x=r_1a_1+...+r_na_n$$ for some $n\in
>  \mathbb{Z}^+$ In this situation we say $A$ is a *basis* or *set of
>   free generators* for $F$. If $R$ is commutative ring, the cardinality
>   of $A$ is called the *rank* of $F$.

**Questions.**

1. Can we define similarly free modules (with the use of direct sum and with infinite cyclic modules)?
2. Is it useful to make such comparisons?

*Thank you in advance.*

---

*Reference: Abstract Algebra, Dummit and Foote, 3rd ed.*

Answer (score 2):

Abelian groups are precisely $\mathbb{Z}$-modules: the data of a $\mathbb{Z}$-module $M$ consists of an abelian group $M$ together with the specification of a ring homomorphism $\eta: \mathbb{Z} \to \text{End}(M)$, where the latter denotes the ring of group endomorphisms of $M$. But there is only one possible ring homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}$ to any ring $S$, given by sending $1 \in \mathbb{Z}$ to the multiplicative unit in $S$, so $\eta$ above is uniquely specified hence adds no additional data to the abelian group structure of $M$.

Hence, free abelian groups are the same thing as free $\mathbb{Z}$-modules. The translation between the definition you gave for free $R$-modules and a formulation given in terms of direct sums can be obtained by observing that having a free $R$-module $F$ on a set of generators $A \subset F$ is equivalent to being able to write down an isomorphism of $R$-modules:

$$ \bigoplus_{a \in A} Ra \to F, \\ (r_a)_{a \in A} \mapsto \sum_{a \in A} r_a a.  $$

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and sorry for the delay. So, an R-module F is called a *free $R$-module* if $F$ is isomorphic to a direct sum
of copies of $R$: that is
$$F\cong R_1 \oplus ... \oplus R_n \oplus ...$$
where $R_i=\langle x_i \rangle \cong R,\ \forall i\in \{1,2,...,n,...\}$. And $X:=\{x_1,...,x_n\}$ is called a *basis* of $F$. Correct?